# How to return boolean array in numba.njit?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, numba

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, float64
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@njit(fastmath=True)
def compare(values1, values2):
    shape = values1.shape[0]
    res = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    
    for i in range(shape):
        res[i] = x[i] > y[i]
    
    return res

spce = [("x", float64[:]),
        ("y", float64[:]),
        ("z", float64[:]),]
        
@jitclass(spce)
class Math:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def calculate(self):
        i = compare(self.x, self.y)
        return self.z[i]
```

If I testing like this:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
compare(x, y)
```

It will return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-586dc5d173c7>", line 3, in <module>
    compare(x, y)

  File "C:\Users\Option00\Anaconda3\envs\bot\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File "C:\Users\Option00\Anaconda3\envs\bot\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)

  File "C:\Users\Option00\Anaconda3\envs\bot\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<built-in function zeros>) found for signature:
 
zeros(int64, dtype=Function(<class 'bool'>))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'zeros': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 504.
    With argument(s): '(int64, dtype=Function(<class 'bool'>))':
   No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function zeros>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-24-69a4f907fb89> (4)
```

Finally I need to use it in the jitclass:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.random.rand(10)

m = Math(x, y, z)
m.calculate()
```

Actually the output is just z[x>y] in numpy, but how i can use in njit & jitclass?

I need both of them for speed up my others code.

If the compare function can be return boolean array, the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use Numba's special `bool_` type for that:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba.types import bool_, int_, float32

@njit(bool_[:,:](float32[:,:,:],float32[:,:,:],int_))
def test(im1, im2, j_delta=1):
    diff = ((im1 - im2)**2).sum(axis=2)/3
    mask = np.zeros_like(diff, bool_)  # <--- like so
    for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
        for j in range(diff.shape[1]):
            mask[i,j] = diff[i,j] > 1.0
    return mask
```

If you replace `bool_` by `bool` or even `np.bool`, you'll get a compile error.

Comment: `np.bool` doesn't work, but `np.bool_` does.